# How to get GET parameters with ASP.NET MVC ApiController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I feel a bit absurd asking this but I can't find a way to get parameters for a get request at
`/api/foo?sort=name` for instance.

In the `ApiController` class, I gave a `public string Get()`. Putting `Get(string sort)` makes `/api/foo` a bad request. Request instance in the `ApiController` is of type `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage`. It doesn't have a `QueryString` or `Parameters` property or anything.

Comment: Is this your get/id or are you trying to do your get?  For a get without id return an IQueryable.  You will need both a GET() and a GET(id) if you want to fully support REST.

Comment: Sorry, should have specified. I'm trying to create an API to return a json whose content is influenced by the get?parameter. I'm not quite exposing the data source directly via the API

Comment: If you need to evaluate on more than the id then you will need to go IQueryable and use Odata.

Comment: If you have Get(string sort), then api/foo and api/foo?sort=name should both route to your Get method. Are you saying you get a 400 error?

Comment: Rick Strahl has a [great blog](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Apr/15/WebAPI-Getting-Headers-QueryString-and-Cookie-Values) about this with some extensions that I ended up using...

Comment: Some additional options in answers to this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12101508/12484

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could just use

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString
```

Comment: this doesn't work in the context of ApiController in mvc3

Answer (score 34):

The ApiController is designed to work without the HttpContext object (making it portable, and allowing it to be hosted outside of IIS).

You can still access the query string parameters, but it is done through the following property:

```
Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
```

Here's an example loop through all the values:

```
foreach (var parameter in Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs())
{
     var key = parameter.Key;
     var value = parameter.Value;
}
```

Comment: GetQueryNameValueParirs() was not available on the Request object. It worked after "using System.Net.Http;"

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example that gets the querystring q from the request and uses it to query accounts:

```
        var q = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().Where(nv => nv.Key =="q").Select(nv => nv.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        if (q != null && q != string.Empty)
        {
            var result = accounts.Where(a=>a.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(q.ToLower()));
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Please specify a search query");
        }
```

This can be called then like this:

url/api/Accounts?q=p

Comment: Or even better:  var q = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().SingleOrDefault(nv => nv.Key =="q");

Comment: You're right, its nicer to write it that way, but in my case add the Select(nv => nv.Value) to it

Answer (score 5):

Get all querystring name/value pairs into a variable:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queryString = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
```

Then extract a specified querystring parameter

```
string value = queryString.Where(nv => nv.Key == "parameterNameGoesHere").Select(nv => nv.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following

```
var value = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().Where(m => m.Key == "paramName").SingleOrDefault().Value;
```

Comment: This might not work as intended when the default value is returned for a KeyValuePair when immediately using .Value on it.

Answer (score 3):

if we have a proper model for that request

for example

```
  public class JustModel 
    {
      public int Id {get;set;}
      public int Age {gets;set;}
    }
```

and query like this

```
/api/foo?Id=1&Age=10
```

You could just use  `[FromUri]` attribute

For example

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAge([FromUri] JustModel model){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to build an OData webservice? If so, just return an IQueryable, and the Web API will do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a default value does the job:

```
public string Get(string sort="")
```