# Accessing the query string in ASP.Net Web Api?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, query-string

I'm using the default template generated by Asp.net Web Api. I'm working with the Get() part:

```cs
// GET api/values
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

For some reason I thought the only thing you had to do to access to query string was just to create an input string variable. So I created one more function (the only change I made) to the default controller generated:

```cs
public IEnumerable<string> Get(string queryString)
{
    return new string[] { "value3", "value4" };
}
```

I put a breakpoint in both methods but even if I add a query string it always goes to the function with no parameters. So if I go to `http://mybaseurl/api/values?foo=f` it still is going to Get() instead of Get(string queryString). Does it not work the way I thought? I know I can access the query string in the Get() function using `Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();` but I prefer to have it separated like this if possible.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The query string key name should match the parameter name of the action:

/api/values?**queryString=f**

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get(string queryString)
    {
        return new string[] { "value3", "value4" };
    }
```

Comment: if there in url we have ?$callback how can fetch that

Answer (score 68):

Even though [@Kiran Challa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1184056/kiran-challa)'s answer is correct, there are few situations that you might prefer to get **URL parameters** directly from the URL. in those scenarios, try this:

```
using System.Net.Http;

var allUrlKeyValues = ControllerContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

string p1Val = allUrlKeyValues.LastOrDefault(x => x.Key == "p1").Value;
string p2Val = allUrlKeyValues.LastOrDefault(x => x.Key == "p2").Value;
string p3Val = allUrlKeyValues.LastOrDefault(x => x.Key == "p3").Value;
```

Now for the following URL, p1Val will be "Apple", p2Val will be "Banana", and p3Val will be *null*.

```
.../api/myController?p1=Apple&p2=Banana
```

### Update:

Thanks for the suggestions, now, the source code for this test is in [GitHub](https://github.com/tohidazizi/FreeWebApi/blob/master/Thrita.Web.Api.FreeWebApi/Controllers/ValuesController.cs) 
and it also runs and can be tested on Azure:

- http://freewebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/values?p1=Apple&p2=Banana

Comment: I get an error 500 if I specify the same query name twice - this is permitted in HTTP (names can have multiple values) but it makes `freewebapi` crash: http://freewebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/values?p1=Apple&p2=Banana&p1=Foo

Comment: You are right @Dai 
 Have to improve the code to avoid that exception. How about replacing .SingleOrDefault() with .FirstOrDefault() or .LastOrDefault() ?

Answer (score 2):

There is one more way to get query string as shown below when you are using wildcard in route or for dynamic routes.

```
string query = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value;
```

BONUS:)

```
string path = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToUriComponent();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will also get you a specific query parmeter by name:

```
string testValue = request.GetQueryParameterDictionary().LastOrDefault(x =>
x.Key == "test").Value;
```