# How to get Request Querystring values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

My api client code sends an authentication token in the querystring like:

```
www.example.com/api/user/get/123?auth_token=ABC123
```

I'm using Mvc Web api controller, and I have a filter that checks if the auth_token is valid or not, but I'm not sure how to access the request querystring values.

This is what I am doing now but it is obviously wrong:

The below snippet is inside of my filter that inherits from:

**ActionFilterAttribute**

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
       base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

       if (actionContext.Request.Properties.ContainsKey("auth_token") &&
          actionContext.Request.Properties["auth_token"].ToString() == "ABC123")
       {
         ...
       }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101508/accessing-the-query-string-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: @muski but I want to do this in a filter, not at the action level.

Answer (score 31):

Use the GetQueryNameValuePairs extension method, like so:

```
var queryString = actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

**EDIT**
To avoid duplicate keys, consider doing a `ToLookup`:

```
var queryString = actionContext.Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs().ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Here's a blog post on Lookups: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/vendettamit/using-lookup-for-duplicate-key-value-pairs-dictionary/

Comment: Butt beware: `ToDictionary` will throw an exception when two parameters with the same key are passed - for instance - [defining an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981330/pass-an-array-of-integers-to-asp-net-web-api).

Comment: You're right. Better would be to project the name/value pairs using `ToLookup`.

Comment: I like this `GetQueryNameValuePairs()`; here's another approach, using `LastOrDefault(...)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/22432384/1175496

Answer (score 10):

In the `OnActionExecuting` method of a filter, you can access the query string and parse it like this to get the token.

```
var queryString = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query;
if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(queryString))
{
    string token = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(
                         queryString.Substring(1))["auth_token"];
}
```

But then, is passing a token in query string a good practice? Probably not, but it is up to you. HTTP header could be a better option since query string can get logged and cached.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, similar to Badri's:

```
string qsValue = string.Empty;
if (Request.QueryString.HasValue)
{
   NameValueCollection queryStringNameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.Value);
   qsValue = queryStringNameValues.Get("auth_token");
}
```