# Authenticate WEB API request with action params

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am interested how to do a MVC WEB API autorization. I have checked [basic authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/basic-authentication) , but I have a different scenario. In my case login params are expected as an action parameter and not inside header.

```
namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
       [RequireHttps]
       [Authorize]
        public void TestRequest(int actionParam, string username, string token, int appID)
        {
              something.......
        }
    }
}
```

I have also found this explanation http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/867071/WebAPI-Security-Custom-Authorization-Filters but would like to know is it possible to access action parameters instead of header value from Authorize?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply get the query string parameters in your `OnAuthorization` override either from the `HttpActionContext` or from `HttpContext.Current.Request`:

see: [How to get Request Querystring values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18983790/how-to-get-request-querystring-values)

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query.Substring( 1 ));
    var username = queryString["username"];
}
```

or see: [Accessing QueryString in a custom AuthorizeAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805920/accessing-querystring-in-a-custom-authorizeattribute)

Add `using System.Web;` then:

```
public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var username = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["username"];
}
```