# how to add custom pagination in datatable with angularjs?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, pagination

I want to custom pagination using datatable with angularjs mvc c#.
i know inbuilt feature is avilable for pagination but don't used it.want to create custom so how can do that i don't know.

here this code for list my user list:

```
 $scope.dtColumns = [
     DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("fullName", "Full Name"),
     DTColumnBuilder.newColumn("email", "Email"),
 ]
 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('ajax', {
         url: "/api/User/UserList",
         type: "GET",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
     })
     .withPaginationType('full_numbers')
     .withDisplayLength(50)
     .withOption('paging', false)
```

here my html code :

```
<table id="userList" datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns"> </table>
```

this my api method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("UserList")]
public IHttpActionResult UserList() {
    Users = db.Users.ToList();
    return Json(Users);
}
```

any one know how can do that then please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [OData](http://www.odata.org) convention to do what you want.

You can use [$top and $skip](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/) URL parameters to achieve what you want

Edit: With this method, your URL will be 
`/api/User/UserList?$top=[your_top]&$skip=[your_skip]` where 
[your_top] will be the number of items you want, and [your_skip] will be the number of items you want to pass.

Eg: 
`$top=10&$skip=0` will be the 10 first items

`$top=10&$skip=10` will be from the 10th to 20th items
... etc

You can see how to deal with query string with aspnet web api [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101508/accessing-the-query-string-in-asp-net-web-api)

At this time, you can use thoses parameters to filter your items.

Comment: hi but in this code how can used $top and $skip and what you want to say i m not understand propare can you please explain this topic other wise give me any hint.

Answer (score 0):

i am refer this blog and able to server side pagination.here this link for blog.

> http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2016/01/datatables-server-side-paging-sorting-filtering-angularjs.html