# Web API - JObject from URI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net

Web API allows me to capture the body of a POST request in a JObject:

```
    $.post('/api/Query/DoSomething', { Foo: "one", Bar: 4 });

    public string Post(JObject data)
    {
        // data is populated
    }
```

However the same technique does not work with a get request and URI parameters.

```
    $.get('/api/Controller', { Foo : "one", Bar : 4 });

    public string Get([FromUri]JObject data)
    {
        // data is empty

    }
```

Any workaround here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because a GET request does not have a body, and hence no content type.  Therefore, Web API does not know that you have JSON in your URL.  You have a few choices:

1. Pass your data as query string parameters, as is traditionally done in GET requests, and change your method to accept those parameters individually, or in a regular class (POCO).
2. Change your GET method to accept a string instead of a JObject, then use JSON.Net to deserialize it manually, e.g. `JObject obj = JObject.Parse(data);`
3. If you're feeling ambitious, you might be able to implement a custom binder to do this.

My recommendation is option 1.  Traditionally, a GET method is just intended to look something up, so you really should only be passing IDs and simple query options anyway.  It is unusual to be passing JSON data in a URL.  Also the length of URLs can be limited by some browsers.  If you find you are needing to pass JSON data, use POST (or PUT) instead.

Comment: Ended up just using POST for all requests.  Had hoped to be able to use GET for when that was semantically correct, but given that our API is generated dynamically, I needed a way for the GET parameters to be dynamic as well (hence the JObject)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object and bind to it using the FromUri.

Check out this solution which I am using https://stackoverflow.com/a/49632564/2463156.